PHP8.3 - Can't load php_curl (Windows 11, Apache 2.4.53)
I can't get PHP8.3 (Win32-vs16-x64) running under Apache 2.4.53 (win64-VS16) to load php_curl, when Apache starts this error is logged:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl'
(tried: C:\\php\\php-8.3.8-Win32-vs16-x64\\ext\\curl (The specified module could not
be found),
C:\\php\\php-8.3.8-Win32-vs16-x64\\ext\\php_curl.dll (The specified procedure could not
be found))
in Unknown on line 0

PHP curl extension referenced in php.ini like this:
extension_dir = "C:\\php\\php-8.3.8-Win32-vs16-x64\\ext"
extension=curl

[curl]
curl.cainfo = "C:/php/php-8.3.8-Win32-vs16-x64/cacert.pem"

C:\php\php-8.3.8-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_curl.dll seems to exist at that location. My PHP folder is in the system path (executing php -v from a command prompt outputs the PHP version info). libcrypto-3-x64.dll and libssl-3-x64.dll are both in that folder.
I previously ran PHP7.3 on this machine, with curl working (although I think it may not have been straightforward to achieve that).
Any advice on how to get curl working?

How did you install the curl extension? What's in your php.ini file related to curl?

the curl extension comes with the PHP installation (in the ext folder). Added a little more info above

I don't know why, but upgrading to Apache 2.4.62 Win64 seems to have fixed it.
